# How do I see why my SVG isn't rendering?

Tags: google-chrome, svg

With Chrome as my target browser, I'm adding a hand-edited SVG image to a webpage. The SVG image doesn't render, and Chrome shows a "broken image" icon in its place.

I suspect that the problem is that my hand-edited SVG has a typo somewhere in it, but without any further information, I'm not sure how to look for the mistake. Some kind of error message would be extremely useful. How do I see the error that prevented Chrome from rendering the SVG?

Comment: Try to open the .svg file directly in the browser ("Open image in new tab"). That should show syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the https://validator.nu/ validator?

Use "File Upload" or "Text Field" and select the SVG preset:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add name space to your svg tag. Like mentioned below. That should make it work.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
</svg>
```